# pip freeze is empty

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I installed numpy in my virtual conda environment "thinkstats", but `pip freeze` is not showing me the numpy for requirements.txt.  Why?

[image]

Unsurprisingly, when I did `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, it gave me an empty txt file.

Comment: `conda list --export`?

Comment: @BradSolomon This output isn't in the right format for `pip install` tho

Answer (score 0):

When pip is installed inside anaconda, `pip freeze` only shows packages installed within the internal pip and not the entire conda environment. Numpy was installed through conda.